# How do I find all javascript anonymous functions accessing a specified property in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, anonymous-function

I'm just servicing quite a large project containing a lot of javascript/angular source codes.
The application log from the production environment contains a record:

> Unable to set property xyz of undefined or null reference at Anonymous
>   function (http://abc...

Incomplete url, no source file specified, no function or further identification.

I need to narrow my search to anonymous functions containing 'xyz' property access.
How do I do it in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Search all files: Ctrl Shift F

Comment: Sure, but I need to narrow my search to find only anonymous functions containing that property access.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to search for something like that. If you search for the property though you'll find all references to it, just go through the list. You need to be able to debug and search in code, there's not always a "quick fix"